# Can't get build artifacts to display properly in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I currently Jenkins to as my continuous integration system and I use Gradle to build my project. Without changing anything Gradle by default puts all the build artifacts under the /build folder in the workspace. This obviously doesn't work well since the build artifacts get overwritten by the following build.

I have modified my script to output the files in the /builds/[BUILD_ID] folder on Jenkins, which puts the build artifacts in the correct build folder on the CI system, but they don't show up in the Jenkins gui when you navigate to a specific build.

How do I get my build artifacts to display in Jenkins? Where do they need to be put, in order to show up for each build?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Post Build Actions section of your Jenkins job configuration, select "Archive the artifacts" and specify which files to archive.  Jenkins will save them with the rest of the build data and provide links to each file on the build page.

Comment: Is it possible it make the artifact links fully browser-clickable, for example so that a text file will open in the browser instead of being downloaded?

Comment: I take back that previous comment, "Archive the artifacts" works great! I was confusing it with Deploying the artifacts (which doesn't give a clickable link).

Comment: I just realized Jenkins stopped putting links to the artifacts on the build page, since I have no idea. Artifacts should be set up to archive...

Comment: Ok I guess the artifacts I have use non-alphanumeric file names. Sad but true, even the future doesn't handle such stuff well :-(